# How does one "give someone a telephone call" in French?

Tags: usage, expressions

There seem to be several different ways of expressing the idea of giving someone a telephone call in French; for example, I've heard the phrase *donnez-moi un coup de fil* used, which presumably means something like "give me a blow of the (telephone) line", but are there any more common expressions than this used?  Would, for example, a French speaker just say *appelez-moi* ("call me") or *téléphonez-moi* ("phone me")?

Comment: How does one give a telephone call in French? Basically it's same than in English, you pick up the phone, dial a number, and so on. Just when you're about to speak, do it in French instead of English. (Short version: you may want to rephrase your title)

Comment: Listen to the [Call Me](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5a/BlondieCallMe.ogg) song sample available on wikipedia, and you'll have the answer at the end ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Appeler*, *téléphoner* et *donner/passer un coup de fil/téléphone* sont les expressions les plus courantes en France. *Appelez-moi* et *téléphonez-moi* sont tout à fait d'usage, pas de problème.

Comment: Pour les moins courantes, on aura *passe-moi un coup de bigo[phone]* que j'entends encore un peu mais qui est évidemment à réserver à un usage familier.

Comment: @LudoMC, c'est aussi vieilli.

Comment: @Un francophone, ou d'jeuns', au choix (c'est dans les vieux pots... cf le verlan).

Comment: @jv42 Exact, bien qu'effectivement vieilli, je l'entends surtout dans la bouche des *d'jeuns'* comme tu dis ! :)

Answer (score 8):

S'il fallait classer par niveau de langue, je ferais la chose suivante:

**Correct** (formal)

> téléphoner
>
> appeler
>
> joindre ( "vous pouvez me joindre au 06..." )
>
> passer un appel

**Familier** (informal)

> passer un coup de fil
>
> passer un coup de téléphone

**Populaire** (popular)

> bigophoner ( "je te bigophone" )

Comment: Existe t-il aussi "sonner", comme "sonne-moi" ? On le voit beaucoup dans d'autres langues mais je me demande si je l'ai jamais vu en français...

Comment: Non, en France ça ne se dit pas. Par contre ça se dit en Belgique je crois.

Comment: @AndrewVit On peut éventuellement *bipper*.

Comment: @Andrew il me semble que l'expression *Sonne-moi* (voire *Fais-moi sonner*) fait référence à autre chose : cette pratique assez répandue consistant à faire sonner le téléphone de quelqu'un un nombre de fois convenu puis de raccrocher avant que l'interlocuteur ne décroche. Souvent pour demander implicitement d'être rappelé. *Bipper* s'utilise de la même manière.

Comment: @RomainVALERI curieusement, ici en Amérique du Nord (anglophone) on ne connait pas du tout cette pratique de "sonner" et raccrocher. Une expression analogue n'existe pas en anglais, mais je connais aussi le verbe tchèque "prozvonit" de même façon, par example pour annoncer notre arrivée ("je suis là") sans autre message. Peut-être seulement un truc Européen?

Answer (score 1):

If you are in Québec, you can use: « câller quelqu'un »:

« Je finis ma réunion et je te **câlle** tout de suite après. »

https://www.dufrancaisaufrancais.com/caler-sans-se-caler/

Or, if you want someone to call you,

« **Câlle**-moi quand t'auras une minute »

Answer (score 0):

Literally call to someone: "telephoner *à* quelqu'on"

Another related answer would be "appeler sur sien mobile"

Comment: I think I am getting confused now ..."appeler quelqu'on sur son mobile" is right for sure. But I need to know the difference between 'appeler' & 'rappeler' and 'sien' & 'son'. But you get the idea

Comment: "Appeler sur sien mobile" is incorrect. Or actually, that might be *syntactically* correct, but no one would understand without having to think about it ;).